# Attempting to understand the difference in computed result for a Math.imul (javascript) recreation in Elixir

Tags: javascript, math, elixir

Currently working on an Elixir project which has a need for the standard javascript [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/imul#description) `Math.imul` functionality. After implementing the method in Elixir, the returned value is vastly different from that of the one produced by Javascript's `Math.imul` (via the [shim](https://github.com/es-shims/Math.imul/blob/main/implementation.js) here which I'm referencing for the recreation) which is an obvious problem if I'm going for value parity. My goal is for the Elixir function to produce the same value as the Javascript one. It appears that all of the values produced within both methods are identical right up until the final result calculation utilizing the bitwise shift left operator.

`imul(-5, 12)` produces...

Javascript:

```
const imul = (x: number, y: number) => {
    const a = ToUint32(x);
    // 4294967291
    const b = ToUint32(y);
    // 12
    const ah = (a >>> 16) & 0xffff;
    // 65535
    const al = a & 0xffff;
    // 65531
    const bh = (b >>> 16) & 0xffff;
    // 0
    const bl = b & 0xffff;
    // 12

    return (al * bl) + (((ah * bl) + (al * bh)) << 16)
    // -60
  }
```

Elixir:

```
def imul(x, y) do
    a = toUInt32(x)
    # 4294967291
    b = toUInt32(y)
    # 12
    ah = (a >>> 16) &&& 0xffff
    # 65535
    al = a &&& 0xffff
    # 65531
    bh = (b >>> 16) &&& 0xffff
    # 0
    bl = b &&& 0xffff
    # 12

    (al * bl) + (((ah * bl) + (al * bh)) <<< 16)
    # 51539607492
  end

  def toUInt32(num) do
    <<num :: integer-unsigned-32>>
    |> :binary.decode_unsigned(:big)
  end
```

I understand somewhat that Elixir operates on integers of arbitrary precision, so you don't need to worry about 32-bit integer limits as in JavaScript. I believe the semantics of bitwise operations are, however, similar in terms of manipulating individual bits so I'm slightly confused at what I'm doing wrong here and what I need to do to arrive at the same value that the canonical (`Math.imul`) method is arriving at, `-60`. Help appreciated!

Comment: @JaromandaX yes - it's simply 

```def toUInt32(num) do
    <<num :: integer-unsigned-32>>
    |> :binary.decode_unsigned(:big)
  end
```

which seems to work correctly as both the JS/Elixir values arrive at the same integer to that point. Correct - the javascript is the "correct" version, the Elixir is currently the "wrong" version.

Comment: @JaromandaX I've updated the description to contain the `toUInt32` method implementation. My goal is to arrive at the same result as the Javascript (canonical) method value of -60 which is correct. Elixir is currently producing a vastly different (incorrect) result of 51539607492, which I'm trying to understand why.

Comment: that answer `51539607492` is as if you `return (al * bl) + (((ah * bl) + (al * bh))  * 2**16)` - so, I believe the issue may be that `(((ah * bl) + (al * bh)) <<< 16)` is producing a 36 bit result, unlike in javascript where bitwise operators always produce 32 bit results - perhaps a simple `&&& 0xffffffff` will help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Elixir doesn't have integer overflows, you don't have to worry about bitshifts and can simply multiply the values, then convert to a signed integer.

```elixir
def imul(x, y) do
  <<result::signed-32>> = <<x * y::32>>
  result
end
```

---

More detailed explanation:

Javascript:

```js
> 1 << 30
1073741824
> 1 << 31
-214748364
```

Elixir:

```elixir
iex> 1 <<< 30
1073741824
iex> 1 <<< 31
2147483648
```

You can see that in Javascript, the result of a bitwise operation is assumed to be a 32-bit signed integer, so bitshifting left causes an integer overflow. In Elixir it is an unlimited-bit signed integer, so bitshifting left does not cause an integer overflow.

If you want to reproduce the same behaviour as Javascript, you have to use the [binary special form](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#%3C%3C%3E%3E/1) to tell Elixir to convert the left-shifted number to a 32-bit signed integer:

```elixir
iex> shifted_left = (ah * bl) + (al * bh) <<< 16
51538821120 # Equivalent to 101111111111111101000000000000000000, 36 bits
iex> <<shifted_left_with_integer_overflow::signed-32>> = <<shifted_left::32>>
<<255, 244, 0, 0>>
iex> (al * bl) + shifted_left_with_integer_overflow
-60
```

But as shown above, the bit-shifting is not necessary in Elixir in the first place.